# Node MySQL Database Location

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I'm creating an desktop application using electron and now I want to connect it to my database. 
For now I just want to test it locally before I buy a web hosting server. 
 This is what I use for connection

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'test'
});
```

So basically I dont even know if test database exist so I check for error using this

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if(err){ console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack); return; }
});
```

And It's not showing any error so far. So in my mind database 'test' does exist, correct me if i'm wrong.

So now where can I find this database ?

Answer (score 0):

try to find data base is there or not using

```
connection.query('show databases', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err)
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  else
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer in which I have to use port. I check my xammp and its port is 3306 and that's the default port for node.mysql. So for now my problem is solved.